# Implementing Maps V2 android

Tags: android, maps

guys i'm trying to implement the new version of google maps, and I've made the steps written in google, but i'm still having errors when trying to run the map from my mobile phone.

here's my java code :

```
package com.example.e_order;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Order_map extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_map);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_order_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here's my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.e_order"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <permission
    android:name="com.example.e_order.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.e_order.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey" />
```

and thats the logcat which appears to me :

```
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.e_order/com.example.e_order.Order_map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:271)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at com.example.e_order.Order_map.onCreate(Order_map.java:12)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    ... 11 more
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-08 21:08:40.355: E/AndroidRuntime(14147):    ... 21 more
```

sry 4 the long quest. :)

the new error :

```
04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable 04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754): at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source) 04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754): at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Btw have you added google play services as library to your project such as this "http://i.stack.imgur.com/mvlfB.jpg".

Comment: yess i've added it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify the class name of the fragment

You should have it like this :

```
<fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
          android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
          android:layout_width="math_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Btw class name should not contain underscore

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the `name` attribute of your `Framgnet` and since you are developing your application to support `SDK < 11` then you should use the `SupportMapFragment` object:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Comment: well at first glance I missed what you saw... so +1 to you too : )

Comment: 04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-08 22:25:47.108: E/AndroidRuntime(19754):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)

Comment: sry the comment isn't complete ... i've did those steps but it gave me a new error in the logcat :(